# Unreal 5.2 - foliage texture missing in build

Tags: unreal-5, build

I'm working on a demo in Unreal 5.2 and I would like to share the build. I noticed that when I cook the build, the foliage is missing. In `Project settings` --> `Packaging`, I made sure to select `Cook everything in the project content directory`.

Image left: terrain in the build (without foliage); image right: terrain in the level viewport (with foliage).

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks
[image]